# PySpark casting IntegerTypes to ByteType for optimization

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading in a large amount of data via parquet files into dataframes. I noticed a vast amount of the columns either have 1,0,-1 as values and thus could be converted from Ints to Byte types to save memory.

I wrote a function to do just that and return a new dataframe with the values casted as bytes, however when looking at the memory of the dataframe in the UI, I see it saved as just a transformation from the original dataframe and not as a new dataframe itself, thus taking the same amount of memory.

I'm rather new to Spark and may not fully understand the internals, so how would I go about initially setting those columns to be of ByteType?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Did you perform some action after the transformations (like `count`, `first`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It might be useful, but in practice impact might be much smaller than you think.

As you noticed:

> the memory of the dataframe in the UI, I see it saved as just a transformation from the original dataframe and not as a new dataframe itself, thus taking the same amount of memory.

For storage, Spark uses in-memory columnar storage, which applies a number of optimizations, including compression. If data has low cardinality, then column can be easily compressed using run length encoding or dictionary encoding, and  casting won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see whether there is any impact, you can try two things:

1. Write the data back to the file system. Once with the original type and anther time with your optimisation. Compare size on disk.
2. Try calling collect on the dataframe and look at the driver memory in your OS's system monitor, make sure to induce a garbage collection to get a cleaner indication. Again- do this once w/o the optimisation and another time with the optimisation.

user8371915 is right in the general case but take into account that the optimisations may or may not kick in based on various parameters like row group size and dictionary encoding threshold.

This means that even if you do see impact, there is a good chance you could get the same compression by tuning spark.